# find hierarchy in xml structure

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am trying to find the hierarchy of ToolID elements and subelements in my XML code by using ElementTree in Python:

```
<Node ToolID="19">
  <GuiSettings Plugin="AlteryxGuiToolkit.ToolContainer.ToolContainer">
  <Properties>
  <ChildNodes>
    <Node ToolID="11">
    <Node ToolID="16">
      <GuiSettings Plugin="AlteryxGuiToolkit.ToolContainer.ToolContainer">
      <Properties>
      <ChildNodes>
        <Node ToolID="17">
          <GuiSettings Plugin="AlteryxGuiToolkit.ToolContainer.ToolContainer">
          <Properties>
          <ChildNodes>
            <Node ToolID="2">
              <GuiSettings Plugin="AlteryxBasePluginsGui.DbFileInput.DbFileInput">
              <Properties>
              <EngineSettings EngineDll="AlteryxBasePluginsEngine.dll" EngineDllEntryPoint="AlteryxDbFileInput" />
            </Node>
          </ChildNodes>
        </Node>
        <Node ToolID="18">
      </ChildNodes>
    </Node>
    <Node ToolID="13">
    <Node ToolID="20">
  </ChildNodes>
</Node>
</Nodes>
```

Desired output for ToolIDs would look like this:
**{10: -}, {19: 11, 16, 13, 20}, {16: 17, 18}, {17: 2}, {2: -}, {11: -}, {18: -}, {13: -}, {20: -}**

Comment: Good luck with the task ..:-)

Comment: To start with, the xml in question is not well-formed. Please edit and fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you could simplify it to something like below if you can change from ElementTree to lxml (for better XPath support)...

**Python**

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("input.xml")

nodes = {}

for node in tree.xpath("descendant-or-self::Node"):  # .//Node was not getting the first Node if it was the root element.
    nodes[node.get("ToolID")] = [child.get("ToolID") for child in node.xpath("./ChildNodes/Node")]

print(nodes)
```

**Input XML** (I tried making your sample XML well-formed. Hopefully the structure is still correct.)

```xml
<Node ToolID="19">
    <GuiSettings Plugin="AlteryxGuiToolkit.ToolContainer.ToolContainer"/>
    <Properties/>
    <ChildNodes>
        <Node ToolID="11"/>
        <Node ToolID="16">
            <GuiSettings Plugin="AlteryxGuiToolkit.ToolContainer.ToolContainer"/>
            <Properties/>
            <ChildNodes>
                <Node ToolID="17">
                    <GuiSettings Plugin="AlteryxGuiToolkit.ToolContainer.ToolContainer"/>
                    <Properties/>
                    <ChildNodes>
                        <Node ToolID="2">
                            <GuiSettings Plugin="AlteryxBasePluginsGui.DbFileInput.DbFileInput"/>
                            <Properties/>
                            <EngineSettings EngineDll="AlteryxBasePluginsEngine.dll" EngineDllEntryPoint="AlteryxDbFileInput"/>
                        </Node>
                    </ChildNodes>
                </Node>
                <Node ToolID="18"/>
            </ChildNodes>
        </Node>
        <Node ToolID="13"/>
        <Node ToolID="20"/>
    </ChildNodes>
</Node>
```

**Printed Output**

```py
{'19': ['11', '16', '13', '20'], 
 '11': [], 
 '16': ['17', '18'], 
 '17': ['2'], 
 '2':  [], 
 '18': [], 
 '13': [], 
 '20': []}
```

If your actual XML has a root element that isn't `Node`, you can still use ElementTree...

```py
for node in tree.findall(".//Node"):
    nodes[node.get("ToolID")] = [child.get("ToolID") for child in node.findall("./ChildNodes/Node")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way.

1. Find all ToolID's

> ```
> tool_id_list = []
> for elm in root.findall(".//Node"):
>     try:
>         tool_id_list.append(elm.attrib["ToolID"])
>     except:
>         pass
> ```

2. Iterate through the list of all available ToolID's and search for child-nodes:

`node_hierarchy = dict((el,[]) for el in tool_id_list)`

```
def find_child_tools(parent_id_list):
    for parent_id in parent_id_list:
        node = (".//Node[@ToolID='%s']/") % (parent_id)
        
        for elm in root.findall(node):
            for elm2 in elm.findall("./Node"):
                child_tool = elm2.attrib["ToolID"]
                node_hierarchy[parent_id].append(child_tool)


find_child_tools(tool_id_list)
node_hierarchy
```

Output:

```
{'10': [],
 '19': ['11', '16', '13', '20'],
 '11': ['8'],
 '8': [],
 '16': ['17', '18'],
 '17': ['2'],
 '2': [],
 '18': ['4'],
 '4': [],
 '13': ['12', '14', '15'],
 '12': [],
 '14': [],
 '15': [],
 '20': []}
```